# netcore 5 redirect from area to root controller with tag helpers not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

When trying to redirect to root controller from my admin area by using routing tag helpers, it doesn't navigate to the root and it navigate to the same area if i have additional routing

**On cshtml**

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home page</a>
```

**The result** : /en/Admin

**It should be** : /en

**On Behind code**

```
string callbackUrl = _helper.GetUrlLeftPart() + url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { area = "", code });
```

**The result** : http://localhost:34/

**It should be** : http://localhost:34/en/Account/ResetPassword

**Routing**

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "MyArea",
        pattern: "{culture:culture}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{culture:culture}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{*catchall}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToDefaultLanguage", culture = defaultCulture });
});
```

**Area controller**

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class HomeController : _BaseAdminController
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Root controller**

```
public class HomeController : _BaseMvcController
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

***----------UPDATE----------***

when provide the culture routing attribute it working well with all tag helpers, is there other method i can use without provide all routing attributes to make that working ? , because when i use tag helpers in the same area without provide the culture routing attribute it working good

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-culture="en">Home page</a>
```

Comment: Please include the code of related controllers with actions.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: There is no .NET Core 5

Comment: I was 3.1 and i have upgraded to 5

Comment: I found that i need to provide the {culture} routing !,
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-culture="en">Home page</a>

Comment: Question updated

Comment: looks like the link generating process cannot determine a value for the segment of `culture` so basically it breaks there. You can provide a default value for `culture` so that if the route value for it is missing, the default culture will be used instead. The pattern should be like this `{culture:culture=en}/...` (default culture is `en`).